# Bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: bluetooth

I've recently installed it on my pc and bluetooth doesn't work at all .
I have hp pavilion laptop.  I've tried to turn it on from system sitting but it's disabled.I tried to take a screenshot to post here but when i take a screen shot and look for it in picture folder i can't find it.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]  
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci  
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:571a Realtek Semiconductor Corp.    
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e8f:00fb GreenAsia Inc.   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command. Do not take pictures. Just copy text from the terminal.

Comment: This Ralink adapter is a real problem. I do not have a good solution.

Comment: so it seems to be difficult to be solved !